# spring-batch sample: why call the constructor method directly?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm looking at the samples for spring-batch and I'm surprised to see a bean constructor method being called directly rather than through a bean reference.  I'm wondering if this is an error.

In https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-batch-example-1/blob/master/src/main/java/com/techprimers/springbatchexample1/config/SpringBatchConfig.java

```
...
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {

    ...

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<User> itemReader() {

        FlatFileItemReader<User> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        ...
        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        return flatFileItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<User> lineMapper() {
      ...
    }
```

Whereas the bean constructor method `lineMapper()` is annotated as `@Bean`, the bean constructor method  `itemReader()` does not inject the bean in its constructor but rather calls `lineMethod()` directly.

I would have expected this definition of `itemReader()`:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<User> itemReader(LineMapper<User> lineMapper) {

    FlatFileItemReader<User> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    ...
    flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
    return flatFileItemReader;
}
```

Isn't this an error in the current spring-batch samples?  Or am I missing something?  Perhaps `@Configuration` does something magic and converts direct calls to constructors into a bean with a proxy?  Perhaps `lineMapper()` doesn't need to be a bean at all?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ways you mentioned will have the same effect which will inject the `LineMapper` bean into the `FlatFileItemReader` 's `@bean` method.

For the `SpringBatchConfig` case , it is using [injecting inter-bean dependencies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/java/configuration-annotation.html#beans-java-injecting-dependencies) feature, which allow to inject a bean into a `@Bean` method via direct method call. And your guess is correct , it works because the `@Bean` method is get proxied by the `ConfigurationClassEnhancer.BeanMethodInterceptor` if you are interested to know how does it works in code level.

Please note this feature will only enable if you are using [full bean mode](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/java/basic-concepts.html#page-title) (i.e. Then `@Bean` method is defined inside the `@Configuration` class)  and `@Configuration` 's `proxyBeanMethods=true` (default value).

Otherwise, any of the following situation will cause calling `lineMapper()` just create a new instance but not accessing the `LineMapper` instance from the spring context :

- Using [lite bean mode](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/java/basic-concepts.html#page-title) :

```java
@Component
public class SpringBatchConfig {


    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<User> itemReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<User> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        ...
        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        return flatFileItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<User> lineMapper() {
      ...
    }
}
```

- Using full bean mode but `proxyBeanMethods=false` :

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class SpringBatchConfig {


    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<User> itemReader() {
        FlatFileItemReader<User> flatFileItemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
        ...
        flatFileItemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
        return flatFileItemReader;
    }

    @Bean
    public LineMapper<User> lineMapper() {
      ...
    }
}
```